# Порядок расположение компонентов по оси Z Delphi

Tags: delphi

На форме есть 3 компонента 2 image и panel . Этот panel нужно разместить между двумя image . Panel создается динамически. как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если при создании компонентов задаются их позиции и  размеры - тогда в чём проблема?

Comment: @MBo документ должен быть под штампом , как это сделать хз документ это panel

Comment: Только  сейчас заметил в заголовке указание на Z-порядок. Чтобы Image рисовался поверх панели, он должен быть её деткой (Panel - его Parent)

Comment: @MBo а как это сделать ? Вообще понятия не имею

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы `TImage` (наследник `TGraphicControl`) отрисовывался поверх `TPanel` (наследник `TWinControl`), он должен либо лежать на каком-либо другом оконном элементе (как я понимаю, здесь это не вариант, поскольку просматривается прозрачность), либо быть дочерним элементом этой панели. Назначить родителя можно так:

```
 Image1.Parent := Panel1;
```

Comment: panel будет уничтожаться назначать его родителям для image не вариант

Comment: Перед уничтожением панели можно поменять родителя. Правда может быть мелькание. Но не проще поместить еще один TImage на панель и делать ему Assign с нужной картинкой? Пусть потом и уничтожается вместе с ней (панелью).

Comment: Может, Вы вообще зря используете компоненты там, где достаточно графических функций

Comment: @MBo можно более поподробнее ?

Comment: Например, TBitmap можно отрисовать на Canvas, указав прозрачный цвет (Transparent + TrasnparentColor)